# How to count one occurrence from multiple colums of the same table MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I wish to count what top 5 keywords are the most used in my table between 5 columns.

So my table is sites and my columns are `"site_motclef1", "site_motclef2", "site_motclef3", "site_motclef4" and "site_motclef5"`

I know how to find the max used keywords one column by one, but I want to count the total in all 5 columns.

Here it's the way I found to count in one column only =>

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) total, site_motclef1
FROM sites
WHERE  `site_active` =  'Yes'
GROUP BY site_motclef1
ORDER BY  `total` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

Some one can drive me ?

Thanks :)

#

I'm trying by this way, but that's don't give me a right result :/
Perhaps I'm in the good way ?

```
select count(*) total, site_motclef
from (
  select site_motclef1 as site_motclef FROM sites WHERE  `site_active` =  'Yes'
  UNION
  select site_motclef2 as site_motclef FROM sites WHERE  `site_active` =  'Yes'
  UNION
  select site_motclef3 as site_motclef FROM sites WHERE  `site_active` =  'Yes'
  UNION
  select site_motclef4 as site_motclef FROM sites WHERE  `site_active` =  'Yes'
  UNION
  select site_motclef5 as site_motclef FROM sites WHERE  `site_active` =  'Yes'
) AS X
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Just a note: This is bad DB design. If you have the chance - change it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I can understand, but how I can optimise the design with those multiples column ?

Comment: Store all keywords in one column and use the same query to get the count

Comment: Using this type of design you need to use union 4 times which is not a good approach performance wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I totally agree with Juergen that you should fix the database design by having a separate table with one row per keyword and site, the problem with your query is the `union` and the lack of `group by`.  It is removing duplicates.  You need to replace it with `union all`:

```
select count(*) total, site_motclef
from (
  select site_motclef1 as site_motclef FROM sites WHERE  `site_active` =  'Yes'
  UNION ALL
  select site_motclef2 as site_motclef FROM sites WHERE  `site_active` =  'Yes'
  UNION ALL
  select site_motclef3 as site_motclef FROM sites WHERE  `site_active` =  'Yes'
  UNION ALL
  select site_motclef4 as site_motclef FROM sites WHERE  `site_active` =  'Yes'
  UNION ALL
  select site_motclef5 as site_motclef FROM sites WHERE  `site_active` =  'Yes'
) AS X
group by site_motclef
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

And if you just want 5, then add `limit 5` to the end.

Comment: Thanks :D
That's perfect for what I want :)
About the design I will think about it, but actually this query is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Having numbers in your column names is almost ever due to a bad DB design. You can solve this by adding 2 new tables that are related to the `sites` table.

```
motclef table
-------------
id
name


site_motclef table
------------------
site_id
motclef_id
```

Then you can find the top 5 keywords like this

```
select m.name, count(ms.motclef_id) as total_count
from motclef m
join motclef_site ms on ms.motclef_id = m.id
group by m.name
```

This design will also make it possible to have more than or less than 5 `motclef` for every `site`.

Comment: Ok fine, I will think later about recoding my php files and the design on that way.
Thanks